Firebase Crashlytics Plugin clashes with data-binding
I can build with plugin version 2.9.9, but the current version 3.0.0 seems to clash when data-binding is enabled:
android.buildFeatures {
    buildConfig true
    dataBinding true
}

This is the exception being thrown:
Executing tasks: [:bundleGoogleRelease] ...

FAILURE: Build failed with an exception.

* What went wrong:
Circular dependency between the following tasks:
:dataBindingGenBaseClassesGoogleRelease
+--- :mergeGoogleReleaseResources
|    \--- :injectCrashlyticsMappingFileIdGoogleRelease
|         \--- :dataBindingGenBaseClassesGoogleRelease (*)
\--- :parseGoogleReleaseLocalResources
     \--- :packageGoogleReleaseResources
          \--- :injectCrashlyticsMappingFileIdGoogleRelease (*)

(*) - details omitted (listed previously)

The release-resources is only a simple AndroidManifest.xml, which is being merged.
Can the circular dependency be suppressed or is version 3.0.0 incompatible?

Can you post app.gradle ?
